# Reading container logs with 'follow' flag, thread is blocked forever

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spotify-docker-client

Given backend, which processes user requests of reading container logs(with *follow* option). Following approach is used:

```
Future<?> f = threadPool.submit(() -> {
  try {
    while (logStream.hasNext()) {
      LogMessage msg = logStream.next();
      String text = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(msg.content()).toString();
      emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().data(text).name(msg.stream().name()));
    }
    emitter.complete();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    emitter.completeWithError(ex);
  }
});
```

Where `threadPool` is just a `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` and `emitter` is Spring's `SseEmitter`.

The problem is: when user no longer wants to read logs, he just closes the connection, but this thread is still running(execution is blocked in `logStream.hasNext()` which is calling `InputStream.read(..)`).

As far as I understand, `hasNext()` will never return `false`(at least while container is running properly), so this loop is endless, and we need to stop it somehow. Possible solution I tried:

```
emitter.onCompletion(() -> {
  f.cancel(true);
});
```

was not successful. No InterruptedException was thrown.

**Question**: Is there any way of unblocking thread? Or maybe there is another approach of solving this problem (i.e. have a possibility to stop waiting for logs)?

Comment: You may set timeout for emitter and user, if he wants to, might connect again, when emitter is closed.

Comment: @kr3v how does it solves the problem?

Comment: What is your problem? Thread loops forever. If you add `onInterrupt` callback on emitter which will interrupt thread, it will do it, as emitter has timeout.

Comment: @kr3v Problem is that interrupting thread(via f.cancel(true)) has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kr3v/3f507e3d37079a2e7b24a42c85bd8f86 - code like this finishes with "Async request timed out" message in logger